# Using Array.prototype.findIndex() to find object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was looking at some examples of using findIndex(), but I think they gave static examples by setting the search value as static variable inside the function.

I want to find the index of an object in an array so I can call it later. 
So far how I did it is as follows:

https://jsfiddle.net/osbb5zgc/5/

```
var array1 = [{name: "Adam", id: 23},{name: "Badam", id: 55}];
var target = 55;

var res = array1.findIndex(function(element){
    return element.id === target;
});

// Returns 1
```

It correctly returns 1 as is the index of {name: "Badam", id: 55}, 
**BUT is there a better way of passing that target-variable into the function? Or will this work in most cases?**

Comment: Just use `indexOf`

Comment: You're no doubt about to update this question to state that the items in the array are actually objects - not simple numbers. That will make this question entirely opinion based - "What is the *best* way to...." is by definition opinion based (My best != next persons best). You will need to specify more on what it is about this approach which does not fit the bill.

Comment: For your specific example, I can't think why `findIndex` won't be a suitable approach or how it can be improved upon. Can you specify your reservations against `findIndex`?

Comment: ...also your jsfiddle still points to the old version.

Comment: @Jamiec: Fiddle is now updated. I realise I should have rephrased the question. I was just referring to previous examples using findIndex to find objects, but who had the 'target' variable inside as a static value. I want to be able to add that value outside the function.

Comment: I dont follow what you mean by "I want to be able to add that value outside the function."

Comment: ... and your fiddle *still* isnt updated in the question BTW.

Comment: @Jamiec, damn I'm not used to jsfidddle, I hope it's updated correctly now.
I meant to ask if there's a better way of passing the target variable into the function rather than setting it outside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If the values in `search_array` is scalar in nature**, then simply use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```
search_array.indexOf(target)
```

**Demo**

```js
var search_array = [5, 12, 8, 130, 44];
var target = 44;

console.log("Index of target is " + search_array.indexOf(target));
```

However, if the value is an *array* or *object*, then `findIndex` is right method to use.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually, in the extension of this is that I want to have objects in the array, perhaps I should had made the question so.

Comment: @JUlinder For objects, `findIndex` is more suitable and `indexOf` won't work.

Comment: Good comment, I think I'll modify the question to be more accurate for what you're saying